# My form posted with jQuery does not send POST variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The following code won't work. The PHP file never received the POST-variables and I don't know why. Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

HTML

```
<div id="preloader" class="preload"></div>
<div id="formarea"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


/*Formulargenerator*/
//$.fn.reload = function() {
//alert("reload data:"+$('#formstep').serialize());
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'system/ajx/form_generator.php?chck=1',
      data: $('#formstep').serialize(),
      success: function(result){
        $('#formarea').html(result);
        alert("Sucess");

      //  $('#beschreibung').each(function() {
      //  $(this).data('default', this.value);
      //    }).focusin(function() {
      //  if ( this.value == $(this).data('default') ) {
      //    this.value = '';    
      //    }
      //  }).focusout(function() {
      //  if ( this.value == '' ) {
      //    this.value = $(this).data('default');    
      //  }
      //  });

      //$('#produktgruppe').change(function(){
      //  $('#formstep').reload();
      //  });

      // $('#formstep').submit( function(){
      //    $('#formstep').reload();
      //  }); 

      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        alert('resultdaten:'+result);
      }
  });
//}


//$('#formstep').reload();


$('#produktgruppe').change(function(){
  $('#preloader').show();
  $('#formstep').reload();
  $('#preloader').hide(); 
});

$('#formstep').submit( function(){
alert('Click Submit');
  $('#preloader').show();
  $('#formstep').reload();
  $('#preloader').hide(); 
});

$('#preloader').hide();
/* Ende Formulargenerator */


});
```

The PHP Part

```
<?php
unset($vres);
echo"GET: $_GET";
print_r($_GET);
echo"POst: $_POST";
print_r($_POST);

function doform($content)
{
  $form='<form id="formstep" method="post" action="#">'.$content.'</form>';
  return $form;
}


if($_GET['chck']==1)
{
  if($_POST['fstep']==1)
  {
    if($_POST['produktgruppe']<=0){ $vres['produktgruppe']='error'; }
  }
  $outstep=1;
}
else
{ $outstep=1; }


if($outstep<=1)
{
  $form='<div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Ich suche</label>
              <select name="produktgruppe" class="sselect '.$vres['produktgruppe'].'" id="produktgruppe"
                  data-validation="required" 
                  data-validation-error-msg="Bitte w&auml;hlen Sie eine Gruppe aus">
              <option></option>
              '.$options['cats'].'
              </select>
            </div>
            &nbsp;<br>
          <input type="hidden" name="fstep" value="1">
          <input type="submit" id="formsubmt" value="weiter" class="button" />';
  die(doform($form));          
}
?>
```

When I use `print_r($_POST)` the `$_POST` array seems to be empty.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: yes there is nothing to see. No errors no parameter - only the GET=chck

Comment: You should prevent the form from being sent as usual: $('#formstep').submit( function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // Make your ajax call here.} Also, you're making a request immediatly after the page has loaded, naturally, the form won't have any data by then...

Comment: i'm sorry i am not sure what you mean - could you give me more example code?

Comment: Provide the #formstep form. Is there name attribute in those input/select fields

Comment: You can see the formstep in the php file. There is a function to create this form.

Comment: You are not cancelling the form submission...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
  var formularGenerator = {
        init: function() {
              this.getForm();

              $(document).on('change', '#produktgruppe', function(){
                  formularGenerator.submitForm();
              });

              $(document).on('submit', '#formstep', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    formularGenerator.submitForm();
              });
        },

        submitForm: function() {
              $('#preloader').show();

              $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'system/ajx/form_generator.php?chck=1',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: $('#formstep').serialize(),
                    success: function(result){
                          $('#formarea').html(result);
                          alert("Sucess");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                          alert(xhr.status);
                          alert(thrownError);
                          alert('resultdaten:'+result); 
                    },
                    complete: function(data) {
                          $('#preloader').hide(); 
                    }
              });
        },

        getForm: function()
        {
              $('#preloader').show();

              $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'system/ajx/form_generator.php?chck=1',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(result){
                          $('#formarea').html(result);
                          alert("Sucess");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                          alert(xhr.status);
                          alert(thrownError);
                          alert('resultdaten:'+result); 
                    },
                    complete: function(data) {
                          $('#preloader').hide(); 
                    }
              });
        }
  }

  $(function(){
        formularGenerator.init();
  });
```

Comment: if i try it nothing wil happend? It seems that the function wont be called to start!? (sorry for my english :-)

Comment: I didn't understand the question, are you asking what will happen when you try this code? It should send the data from form asynchronously to the system/ajx/form_generator.php?chck=1 when either #produktgruppe is changed or the form #formstep is submitted. The script is initialized at the very bottom - formularGenerator.init();

Comment: no i try your code but nothing will happen. there is no actions. The form wont generate, it wont start. Maybe i have to add something more to your code!? It should be inside of $(document).ready(function() {..your code }?

Comment: No, it's initialized at the very bottom, you can just place it as is. Does the inspector (or any other debugging tool you're using) report any errors or something?

Comment: ok, i removed the document-ready part. But its the same problem. nothing gonna happend. The firebug-console report nothing. No java calles, no errors...

Comment: Are you sure you've copied all the code, including the formularGenerator.init()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108281/discussion-between-4usolutions-and-eihwaz).